# How to integrate two react components to work together in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to this platform and I'm studying React. I have been trying to solve this issue that I simplified a lot to post here. I have two different jsx files from the same web app, but I want the user to interact with the first one, and the result appear on the second component. I basically need to share state between components and I couldn't understand how to do that properly so far.

In this example, the user clicks a button that changes the state of a const (chooseColor) which starts as 'blue' and becomes 'red'. The result of the change should appear on the other component, getting the state from chooseColor. Here are the two different simplified components:

```js
const PartOne = () => {

    const [chooseColor, setChooseColor] = useState('blue')
    
    const changeColor = (newColor) => {
        setChooseColor(newColor)
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={() => changeColor('red')}>Click here to change color</button>
    )
}

export default PartOne

/* SECOND COMPONENT STARTS*/

const PartTwo = () => {
    
    const finalResult = (colorResult) => {
        return <span>The current color is (colorResult)</span>
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {finalResult(chooseColor)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PartTwo
```

React expects me to use the chooseColor in the first component, but it should be useful on the second component. I tried to export things but it got confusing.

Comment: How you do this depends on how you use those components. There are multiple ways of doing it, the default is to pass shared data as properties.  something like `<PartTwo chooseColor={chooseColor} />` and `<PartOne chooseColor={chooseColor} setChooseColor={setChooseColor} />` and keep the state in the parent component instead of inside the `PartOne` component.

Comment: After the default Higher Order Component way where you move the state to a parent. 
If that is being a pain then create a context, wrap the components in a context provider (technically also an HOC) and call useContext in PartOne and PartTwo.  If you have to change multiple pieces of state at a time then put a reducer in the context rather than state and call useReducer in PartOne and PartTwo.

Comment: it took me a while to find a working example.  lifting state up worked better as a search term.  In this example app is the parent that manages state and passes it down to AddtoDo, TodoList, and Counter.  Please note how the parent has to pass addHandler to AddtoDo so the child can change the state stored in the parent:  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-lift-state-up-sidaman-b7h8j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, you have two ways to implement this thing

1. you can create the parent component and call both component (PartOne/ PartTwo)
2. second option you can used context api hook in reactjs

here is the both example

1 =>

```
 const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [chooseColor, setChooseColor] = useState('blue');

  const changeColor = (newColor) => {
    setChooseColor(newColor);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <PartOne chooseColor={chooseColor} changeColor={changeColor} />
      <PartTwo chooseColor={chooseColor} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;

const PartOne = ({ chooseColor, changeColor }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => changeColor('red')}>Click here to change color</button>
  );
};

export default PartOne;

const PartTwo = ({ chooseColor }) => {
  const finalResult = (colorResult) => {
    return <span>The current color is {colorResult}</span>;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {finalResult(chooseColor)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PartTwo;
```

2 => ************************************************

```
    const ColorContext = createContext();

const ColorProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [chooseColor, setChooseColor] = useState('blue');

  return (
    <ColorContext.Provider value={chooseColor}>
      {children}
    </ColorContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ColorProvider;

const PartOne = () => {
  const chooseColor = useContext(ColorContext);

  const changeColor = (newColor) => {
    setChooseColor(newColor);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={() => changeColor('red')}>Click here to change color</button>
  );
};

export default PartOne;

const PartTwo = () => {
  const chooseColor = useContext(ColorContext);

  const finalResult = (colorResult) => {
    return <span>The current color is {colorResult}</span>;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {finalResult(chooseColor)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default PartTwo;
```

---

and also you can used any store management library like (redux and recoil) you can try this one

you have another option also but this is not right way to do it you can used local storage, you can save the data in local storage and in partTwo component get the data from local storage.

Comment: You made it much clearer. Thank you!